# svg-android on 4.1.2 or 5.0 doesn't draw

Tags: android, svg, imageview

I'm trying to display an SVG image in my Android 4.X APP (I've debugged it on my Nexus7 Android 5.0 and my Moto. Razr i Android 4.1.2). I'm using [svg-android](https://code.google.com/p/svg-android/). I think I've tried everything..

Here's my code:

```java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ImageView imageView = new ImageView(this);
    SVG svg = SVGParser.getSVGFromResource(getResources(), R.raw.hsv);
    imageView.setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    imageView.setImageDrawable(svg.createPictureDrawable());
    setContentView(imageView);
}
```

And that's the [result](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_u6lqqDkvr4a0huTC0tMHh4ZEk/view).

Comment: Can't view your result link.  Permission change needed?

Comment: Also, show us your SVG.  svg-android has limitations on the features of SVG it supports.  You may have better luck with my library: AndroidSVG.

Comment: [That's](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/6/66/HSV-Logo.svg) one of the SVG's I'd like to display..

@PaulLeBeau [this](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I've found an solution.. I switched to Paul LeBeaus's [AndroidSVG](https://code.google.com/p/androidsvg/)

There's one small issue. The SVGImageView got some problems with the layout file..

Answer (score 0):

Your SVG contains `style` attributes.  For example:

```
<rect style="stroke:none; fill:#0A3F86;" x="-212" y="-150" width="424" height="300" />
```

Last time I checked, svg-android didn't support style attributes.  If you change them to style properties, I think it will work in svg-android.

For example, the above line would become:

```
<rect stroke="none" fill="#0A3F86" x="-212" y="-150" width="424" height="300" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the info! Unfortunately I can't change the xml, since I obtain the images dynamically from wikimedia.. or maybe I could, but that's not my goal. I'll work with your lib!